# How to avoid rendering FlatList after change state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects that I display using FlatList .

In my parent component, I have a state `isModalDeleteVisible` and a button that allows to change this state .

When I press the button (= that I change the state), the whole FlatList is rendering again (I see it at `console.log()` which is redisplayed).

I understood that a change of state rerend the whole component; I also know that `useCallback()` helps prevent this by memorizing a function . But in this specific situation I cannot prevent the re-rendering of FlatList

`IndexScreen.js` :

```
... 
const IndexScreen = () => {
  const [isModalDeleteVisible, setModalDeleteVisible] = useState(false)

  const onDelete = useCallback(
    () => setModalDeleteVisible(!isModalDeleteVisible),
    [isModalDeleteVisible]
  )

  const listRenderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <Children
        item={item}
        index={index}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Template>
      <Button
        onPress={onDelete}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={dataList}
        renderItem={listRenderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </Template>
  )
}

export default IndexScreen
```

`Children.js` :

```
...

const Children = ({ item }) => {

  console.log(item.id)

  return (
     ...
  )
}

export default Children
```

Comment: Another thing that wasn't mentioned in the answers is this: `keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}`. You're using an anonymous arrow function as the value for `keyExtractor` which causes the reference of that function to change on every render of the `IndexScreen` component. The function reference change will in turn cause your `FlatList` component to be re-rendered. So you will need to define a named function for your `keyExtractor` prop and use it there.

Comment: And something else you can do to improve your performance is to extract `listRenderItem` function and the `keyExtractor` function outside of the `IndexScreen` component. Because they're not dependant on the state or props of the component.

Comment: Also see [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `useCallback` only memoizes the function, which does nothing at preventing rendering `FlatList`.

If you want to prevent `FlatList` rerendering as long as its props don't change, then you should use `React.memo()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

check out flashlist from shopify, it is so fast and it can solve most of your problems. [check it out here](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/)